# How to get random id from database using random_between

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I try something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE aspect_id = (SELECT floor(random(aspect_id)::int FROM generate_series(1,8));
```

and I want to get several aspect_id from table.
Or I try to

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE aspect_id = SELECT random_between(1,100) FROM generate_series(1,5);
```

But still nothing
Could you help me?

Comment: Have you tried `WHERE aspect_id IN = ...` ? Because you will get multiple ids.

Comment: @AntonGriduhsko . . . It is  not clear what results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT * FROM atable
WHERE aspect_id BETWEEN 1 AND 100
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 5;
```